# Изменить цвет текста в items бокового меню android

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Не изменяется цвет текста в меню

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"
    app:itemTextColor = "@color/colorAccent"
    >
 <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/account_image"
        android:title="@string/account_item"
        />
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Mac"
            android:title="@string/mac_item"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Ipad"
            android:title="@string/ipad_item" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Iphone"
            android:title="@string/iphone_item" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Watch"
            android:title="@string/watch_item" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_accessories"
            android:title="@string/accessories_item" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/communicate_item">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/share_item" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/send_item" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно в xml вашей активности прописать в виджете такие строки:

```
android:background="@color/color_navigation_list_background"
app:itemIconTint="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"
app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"
```

в итоге будет выглядеть так:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    android:background="@color/color_navigation_list_background"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"/>
```